# How can you remove the odata.etag when using the Get Entities action with an Azure Table?

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

How can you avoid getting the odata.etag when getting entities from an Azure Table?

The "Get entities result" has an "odata.etag" ...

```
[{
        "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2020-05-19T14%3A33%3A23.31704Z'\"",
        "PartitionKey": "author",
        "RowKey": "1",
        "Timestamp": "2020-05-19T14:33:23.31704Z",
        "AuthorName": "steve",
        "ChapterTitle": null,
        "Twitter": "@steve"
    }, {
```

Whereas if I go through the REST API with the Accept header set to `application/json;odata=nometadata`, I can get the data without any OData extra bits, e.g.

```
{
    "value": [{
            "PartitionKey": "author",
            "RowKey": "1",
            "Timestamp": "2020-05-19T14:33:23.31704Z",
            "AuthorName": "steve",
            "Twitter": "@steve"
        }, {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some tests, it seems the field `odata.etag` can't be avoided in the response data in logic app. If you don't want this field, you can request the REST API in logic app. Just like my logic app shown below:

[image]

Or you can use an [integration account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account), bind it with your logic app. And then use [Liquid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#add-the-liquid-action-for-json-transformation) map to remove the `odata.etag` field from the json response from the "Get entities" action.

**Update:**

Here is another workaround which could be more simple for your reference, we can use "[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action)" in logic app.

[image]